# Слайдер фонового изображения с помощью slick slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать слайдер фонового изображения при помощи `slick slider`?
 Гугл не помогает( В документации сказано что картинки нужно поместить в `div` блок. Но как быть с фоновыми изображениями?

```css
@charset utf-8;
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,
abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,
strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,
legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{background: none repeat scroll 0
0 transparent; border: 0 none; font-size: 100%; outline: 0 none; vertical-align: 
baseline;margin: 0;padding: 0;}table{border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;}
address,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,
section,summary{display: block;}

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

a, a:hover, button, button:hover, .anime {
 -moz-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -ms-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -o-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -webkit-transition:all 200ms linear;
 transition:all 200ms linear;
 cursor: pointer;
}


.F_COL_C-START_I-CENTER {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
}

.F_ROW_C-START_I-CENTER {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
}

.F_ROW_C-S-B_I-F-S {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: flex-start;
}

.F_ROW_C-START_I-STRETCH {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: stretch;
}

body {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #413d4b;
 font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.87vmax;
 line-height: 1.37vmax;
} 

.wrap {
 width: 58.75vw;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85)), url(../img/bg_header.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#top_header {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 margin-top: 3.2vh;
}

#logo svg{
 height: 3vw;
}

#top_header nav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;

}

nav li{
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
 margin-left: 1.25vw;
}

nav a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
 color: #00e0d0;
}

#header_content {
 margin-top: 24.4vh;
}

#header_content h2{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2vw;
 text-align: center;
}

hr {
 border: none;
 width: 3.12vw;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #00e0d0;
 color: #00e0d0;
 margin-top: 3.8vh;
}

#header_content p {
 width: 48.6vw;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 3.5vh;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 4.17vh;
}

.btn {
 padding: 0.8vw 1.5vw;
 font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1vw;
 color: #00e0d0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 1px solid #00e0d0;
 background-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-top: 7.3vh;
}

.btn:hover {
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#dot_nav{
 width: 3.43vw;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: flex-start;
 margin-top: 18.9vh; 

}

.circle_nav {
 width: 0.62vw;
 height: 0.62vw;
 border: 2px solid #bab9bc;
 background-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 0.62vw;

}

.circle_nav:hover {
 border: 2px solid #00e0d0;
 background-color: #00e0d0; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Landing Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
 
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap ">
   <div id="top_header">
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Expertise</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">People say</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>

   <div id="header_content" class="F_COL_C-START_I-CENTER">

    <h2>We Are Awesome Creative Agency</h2>

    <hr />

    <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.</p>
     
    <button class="btn" type="button">Learn More</button>
    
    <div id="dot_nav">
     <div class="circle_nav"></div>
     <div class="circle_nav"></div>
     <div class="circle_nav"></div>
     <div class="circle_nav"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 

 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, почему нет. Слайдам через `css` задайте высоту(если нет контента) и фон.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows:false,
  dots:true,
  customPaging:function(){return ''}
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.slide{
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;  
}
.slide.slick-slide{
  min-height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}
.slick-dots{
  margin:10px 0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.slick-dots li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:.5;
  transition:all .2s ease;
  margin:0 5px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.slick-dots .slick-active{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(https://winzoro.net/uploads/posts/2012-07/1333997806_220817.jpg)"></div>  
  <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-95803396.jpg)"></div>  
  <div class="slide" style="background-image:url(https://cs5.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/09/14/10/1442252185_26762581.png)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь) То-есть фон нужно задавать через html? А через сss не получится?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Можно и через `css`. Но с точки зрения удобства дальнейшей посадки на `cms` лучше так (на мой взгляд).